# Adding data using dagshub.upload.Repo(USER_NAME,REPO_NAM)

Tags: upload, dvc, dagshub

I want to add a raw dataset file to my dagshub repo (my first repo, and its being used alongside an MLflow tutorial)

This is the line that is giving me trouble:

```
repo = dagshub.upload.Repo(USER_NAME,REPO_NAME)

repo.upload(local_path='data/winequality.txt',
            remote_path='data/raw/winequality.txt',
            commit_message='Added Raw Data',
            versioning='dvc')
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Uploading files (1) to "USER_NAME/REPO_NAME"...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DagsHubAPIError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-e8d1e8493248> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 repo = dagshub.upload.Repo(USER_NAME,REPO_NAME)
      3 
----> 4 repo.upload(local_path='data/winequality.txt',
      5             remote_path='data/raw/winequality.txt',
      6             commit_message='Added Raw Data',

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/dagshub/upload/wrapper.py in upload(self, local_path, commit_message, remote_path, **kwargs)
    286         else:
    287             file_to_upload = DataSet.get_file(str(local_path), remote_path)
--> 288             self.upload_files([file_to_upload], commit_message=commit_message, **kwargs)
    289 
    290     def upload_files(

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/dagshub/upload/wrapper.py in upload_files(self, files, directory_path, commit_message, versioning, new_branch, last_commit, force)
    375             timeout=None,
    376         )
--> 377         self._log_upload_details(data, res, files)
    378 
    379         # The ETag header contains the hash of the uploaded commit,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/dagshub/upload/wrapper.py in _log_upload_details(self, data, res, files)
    413             log_message(f"Got unknown successful status code {res.status_code}")
    414         else:
--> 415             raise determine_upload_api_error(res)
    416 
    417     def _poll_mirror_up_to_date(self):

DagsHubAPIError: file missing from storage:
Required resource is missing from the storage, is '' stored in your repository DagsHub storage?
```

The Repo file structure looks like this:
Local disk:
root/
  |...data/
    |... winequality.txt

Remote:
root/
  |...data/
     |...raw/

Note that 'raw' is version controlled by DVC, but the dagshub documentation shows that this is the way to do it: [Upload Data](https://dagshub.com/docs/feature_guide/dagshub_storage/upload_data/)

Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Hi there, Dean from the DagsHub team. It's hard to know 100% without being able to reproduce this locally, but the error message seems to suggest that the file name is an empty string. Have you successfully uploaded some other file to the repo?

One possible thing to check is if there's already a folder tracked in the remote, it might require the `force=True` to update them.

Comment: Hey Dean thank you. My repo is here:
https://dagshub.com/delta2echo/MLflow.Demo

I feel like I am missing something obvious since I know this should be simple. 
I have successfully uploaded other files, but not a datafile in the way shown above.

Comment: I see, thanks for sharing. Looking at that repo it seems like you're missing some DVC files that should be there previously: https://dagshub.com/delta2echo/MLflow.Demo/src/main/data/raw.

I guess it's failing since you're trying to upload to a folder but it can't find the current folder contents.

I see what the issue here is. Since you started with a template that has some structure with DVC but files aren't pushed into it properly, it won't let you add anything new. If you try a different path that doesn't yet exist, it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused due to missing DVC tracked files which prevent adding new files to the directory. To solve the issue, run the following code:

`pip install dvc "dvc[s3]"` if not already installed.

```bash
git clone https://dagshub.com/<user_name>/<repo_name>.git
cd <repo_name>

dvc remote add origin --local s3://dvc
dvc remote modify origin --local endpointurl https://dagshub.com/<user_name>/<repo_name>.s3

dvc remote modify origin --local access_key_id <your_token>
dvc remote modify origin --local secret_access_key <your_token>
```

Then once things are configured, run the following:

```bash
mkdir -p data/raw
dvc commit data/raw.dvc
dvc push -r origin
```

Then run your code. It will now work!

That being said this is probably something we can improve on our end too, so I'll share it with the engineering team!

Thanks for the question :)

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I followed the instructions you outlined but end up with this error: 


|Collecting          |3.00 [00:00, 58.5entry/s]
|Pushing
|Querying remote cache:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?files/s]
|Querying remote cache:   0% 0/1 [00:00<?, ?files/s{'info': ''}]
|Pushing
|ERROR: unexpected error - [Errno 5] An error occurred (401) when calling the |HeadObject operation: Unauthorized: An error occurred (401) when calling the |HeadObject operation: Unauthorized
|
|Having any troubles? Hit us up at https://dvc.org/support, we are always happy to help!

Comment: That error is an authentication error, have you put in your correct username, repo name and access token into the setup commands I provided?

Comment: Yes you are correct! I had a typo. Thank you for all your help!